# T4 code generation: access types in current project

Tags: c#, .net, t4

Using T4 code generation, is it possible to access the types defined in the current project?

For example, if I have an interface and I want to delegate its implementation to another class, i.e.

```
interface IDoSomething {
    public void do_something();
}

class DoSomethingImpl : IDoSomething {
    public void do_something() {
        // implementation...
    }
}

class SomeClass : IDoSomething {
    IDoSomething m_doSomething = new DoSomethingImpl();

    // forward calls to impl object
    public void do_something() {
        m_doSomething.do_something();
    }
}
```

I would like to automate the call-forwarding in `SomeClass` with code generation; is this possible?

Comment: Ask yourself how you would do this if it were not generated code. Then take that solution and have the template generate it.

Comment: @John Saunders: this comment was pretty useless, wasn't it?

Comment: I didn't think it was. Maybe _you_ get how to do this, but not everyone understands the process of starting from something that works, then parameterizing it in a template.

Comment: @John: I don't know, maybe you are right and not everybody gets it. Anyway here the point was how to access the type definitions in the project, not how to parametrize an existing snippet...

Comment: Did anyone answer the question using just T4 yet? Because I don't need to look for other solutions, just iterate via reflection for my needs.

Comment: I expect this isn't possible as you have a kind of chicken and egg situation.  I achieved something like this by moving the interface to another assembly, then you can just use typeof(IDoSomething).  Might not be possible in your situation.  HTH

Answer (score 1):

While this doesnt solve the locking problems (although ive heard that VS2010 does), you could try copy the dll to a temp location and just use that copied assembly..

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#    
var newFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
System.IO.File.Copy(@"C:\Development\CustomAssembly.dll",newFileName,true);

var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(newFileName);
var type = assembly.GetType("CustomAssembly.DummyClass");   
#>
<#=newFileName#>
<#=type#>
```