# How do you use .net Reflection with T4?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, t4

I have a c# project which includes a Text Template. I would like this template to generate some SQL based on reflecting against the C# classes in the project.

How does one access the current project's contents using T4? Is it possible, and if so, is Reflection available, or is it access to just the raw source that must then be parsed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153542/t4-code-generation-access-types-in-current-project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does one access the current project's contents using T4?

One way is to use the EnvDTE COM component.  Googling T4 and EnvDTE should bring back plenty of examples.

> Is it possible, and if so, is Reflection available, or is it access
>   to just the raw source that must then be parsed?

Reflection is definitely available from T4.  It works mostly as you would expect.

[Oleg Sych](http://www.olegsych.com/) has a number of great blog entries regarding common T4 usage scenarios, but there are plenty of other resources for T4 out there as well.

Comment: Reflection is generally considered a bad method via T4 because it locks files or assembly so you can't edit it, the EnvDTE COM doesn't have this limitiation

Comment: @Maslow: Anytime you access a DLL in any way from T4 inside Visual Studio (reflection or not), the DLL gets locked and cannot be easily changed without closing Visual Studio and reopening it.  I personally consider that a bug in the Visual Studio T4 implementation (Microsoft would likely argue it is a caching feature).  The lock happens with EnvDTE as well, but you aren't trying to change that DLL, so you don't notice it got locked and it doesn't matter.  This locking issue has nothing specifically to do with reflection, it happens even when you aren't using reflection.

Comment: @Michael - Oleg Sync says specifically not to use reflection from within T4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153542/t4-code-generation-access-types-in-current-project  I don't know the reasoning, and maybe the context there was different, but that's what I was adding to this thread, I should have found the link and included it in the initial comment.

Comment: @Maslow: I'm aware of that post by Oleg (I upvoted orsogufo's comment above a long time ago) and I think I now understand what you are trying to communicate.  Yes, for the scenario in this question, there are better options than reflection that won't lock DLLs.  Calling a method on a DLL is what causes the DLL to get locked and there are ways to inspect a DLL without calling methods.  Thanks.

Comment: @Maslow: T4 locks assemblies in memory.  Imagine you have a template where you grab your recently built dll and start reflecting against it.  The next time you try to build, it would fail because the file is locked and cannot be overwritten.  This behavior is changing in SP1, fortunately, so reflection will be A-OK in T4 templates.

Comment: Reflection becomes viable in Vs2010 SP1 it appears.

Comment: Reflection in T4 was specifically addressed http://blogs.msdn.com/b/t4/archive/2011/03/25/vs2010-sp1-t4-improvements-summary.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Completely aside from locking problems, be careful using reflection within a T4 template. The template generator in VS2010 runs against version 4.0 of the Framework, so you could introduce unwanted dependencies if you're generating code for 3.5 or below.

I just found this out the hard way, after using reflection to decide whether to generate parameterless or parameterised calls to `ToString` for various BCL types. `TimeSpan` has only `ToString()` in 2.0, but 4.0 adds `ToString(string)` :P

Answer (score 0):

While this doesnt solve the locking problems (although ive heard that VS2010 does), you could try copy the dll to a temp location and just use that copied assembly..

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#    
var newFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
System.IO.File.Copy(@"C:\Development\CustomAssembly.dll",newFileName,true);

var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(newFileName);
var type = assembly.GetType("CustomAssembly.DummyClass");   
#>
<#=newFileName#>
<#=type#>
```

Comment: Yes this avoids locking the original file, but the AppDomain loads the assembly once and won't load it again (regardless of the file name).  I have been unsuccessful in loading the file in a new app domain for the purposes of unloading it again when finished.

Comment: Load assembly as byte array using underlying stream