# How to auto generate Decorator pattern in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I have some interface, and a class implementing this interface, say:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
     void Func1();
     void Func2();
}

class Concrete : IMyInterface
{
     public virtual void Func1() { //do something }
     public virtual void Func2() { //do something }
}
```

Now, I want to create a class that decorates each of the concrete class methods with some specific logic, to be executed in non production environment, before and after the call.

```
class Decorator : Concrete
{ 
     public override void Func1() { Pre(); base.Func1; Post(); }
     public override void Func2() { Pre(); base.Func2; Post(); }
}
```

My question is there a simpler way to auto generate such class other than use reflection on the interface and create a text file with cs extension?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally I would just explicitly log where needed, but if you are set on using a decorator to do this you could use the [RealProxy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy.aspx).

It could look something like this:

```
public class DecoratorProxy<T> : RealProxy
{
    private T m_instance;

    public static T CreateDecorator<T>(T instance)
    {
        var proxy = new DecoratorProxy<T>(instance);
        (T)proxy.GetTransparentProxy();
    }

    private DecoratorProxy(T instance) : base(typeof(T))
    {
        m_instance = instance;

    }
    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        IMethodCallMessage methodMessage = msg as IMethodCallMessage;
        if (methodMessage != null)
        {
            // log method information

            //call method
            methodMessage.MethodBase.Invoke(m_instance, methodMessage.Args);
            return new ReturnMessage(retval, etc,etc);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The Invoke message should return something, so I returned the original message. Than the original method was called, but I got the following exception: 
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException : The method was called with a Message of an unexpected type. Any thoughts?

Comment: Looking into MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy.aspx) a type of IMethodReturnMessage should be returned. How do I simply create one?

Comment: new ReturnMessage(retval) - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.returnmessage.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick. Please edit your answer accordingly... Interesting link: http://tdanecker.blogspot.com/2007/09/interception-with-proxies.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp)? It can help you automatically "instrument" classes and achieve your logging scenario without actually creating decorators.

Comment: be careful with any AOP tool - if you company needs to SOX compliant then it may not be an option for you

Comment: Thanks, but I want something free... What is SOX?

Comment: PostSharp has a free community edition. You don't have to buy it! Just go to the downloads page.

Answer (score 2):

What about the Logging Application block?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647183.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but my original question was not accurate - I don't do logging in the simplest sense. I do some pre and post logic... 1 up for this library

Comment: Given new experience I would suggest people landing here should look at policy interception.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a T4 template capable of generating decorator for fairly complex classes based on some simple conventions. The project can be found on GitHub - [T4Decorators](https://github.com/bigT/T4Decorators). Works similar to T4MVC, that is where I got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use T4 and reflection?

Maybe these other questions could help:

- [T4 Code generation: Access types in current project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153542/t4-code-generation-access-types-in-current-project)
- [How do you use .Net reflection with T4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856885/how-do-you-use-net-reflection-with-t4)

Answer (score 1):

We have the same requirement and wrote a Roslyn generator to do this, take a look here: https://github.com/proactima/ProxyGen 
You need to modify the code slightly to fit your needs. Basically we wrap the methods of an interface (all from a certain namespace) in a 'ReliableServiceCall' method. It's trivial to modify this to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach here is to use Decorator Pattern via interfaces.  I know this is a very old post, but if you use an IoC injector, like SimpleInjector, you can setup these decorator calls in 1 line of code.  Then you can do something like this:

```
public class Decorator : IMyInterface
{ 
     private readonly IMyInterface _next;

     public Decorator (IMyInterface next) { _next = next; }

     public override void Func1() { Pre(); _next.Func1; Post(); }
     public virtual void Func2() { Pre(); _next.Func2; Post(); }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that every time you change the interface, you'll have to change your decorator implementation (even if it's very simple implementation). This why this question was specifically asking about "Auto Generate" and not the right pattern to do it...

Comment: If you have a generic interface that is used across everything then you can do this.  That being said, they had defined one interface with multiple concrete implementations, not that they were going to have multiple interfaces to implement.  This should be fine.