# initialize a class from an existing instance of a base class with minimum amount of code

Tags: c#, inheritance

I would like to create a wrapper class that replaces a specific method or property of an existing class with a minimum amount of code

I could use the decorator pattern but it's not very clean.  I would end up having to basically re-declare every method and property in the wrapped class even though I'm only overriding one or two of them and additionally would have to maintain the interface.

I could use extension methods but I want to override an existing method or property so that won't work and even if an extension method could override an existing method, I wouldn't want it to override the method for every instance.

The best I can come up with is something like

```
    public MyDerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
      MyDerivedClass(BaseClass obj)
      {
       this.x = obj.x; this.y=obj.y etc.....
      }

     public override string BaseMethod()
     {
     }

}
```

what I really want is something like

```
    public MyDerivedClass:BaseClass
    {
      MyDerivedClass(BaseClass obj)
     {
       base = obj;
     }

     public override string BaseMethod()
     {
     }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385651/how-to-auto-generate-decorator-pattern-in-c). I really liked the [RealProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy.aspx) solution.