# How to automate the creation of integration tests for controllers?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nunit, restsharp

In efforts to create integration tests around approximately 100 controllers, with methods such as:

```
    [Route("Lead", Name = "GetLeadsUsingQueryOptions")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Lead> GetLeadsUsingQueryOptions(ODataQueryOptions oDataQueryOptions)
    {
        var leads = _leadService.GetLeads(oDataQueryOptions);
        return leads;
    }
```

A corresponding integration tests would be something like:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetLeadsUsingQueryOptions_Returns_IEnumerable_Of_Leads()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("Lead", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("X-Request-ID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        request.AddHeader("X-Client-ID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        request.AddParameter("filter", @"LeadId eq guid'"+TestConstants.LeadGuid.ToString()+"'&amp;$top=5", ParameterType.QueryString);
        var response = GetTestClient().Execute<List<Xrm.Lead>>(request);

        Console.Write(request.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Data.DumpToString("Response"));

        Assert.That(response.Data, Is.InstanceOf<IEnumerable<Xrm.Lead>>());
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
```

**Rather than having to create separate tests for every method in every controller, would it be possible to create either a T4 template, or something else in order to just apply the integration test against all methods in all controllers?**

Comment: It's not clear from the question what are the controller objects, and how they differ from each other? Once you clarify that you can probably have some quality answers (e.g. around parameterized tests)...

Comment: controllers are just the same controllers as in the context of web API

Comment: Let me try and clarify: in order to have some generic solution for testing 100 different objects, you first have to identify how those objects are related (e.g. implementing the same interface, all inheriting from ApiController etc...), than you can look into solutions... I've had a question that may be related (again, not sure what your issue is): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385651/how-to-auto-generate-decorator-pattern-in-c-sharp